# Why I can not show my MySQL information in my GUI table?

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface

I have a "Manager" class and "BirthList" frame. In my BirthList frame I have a GUI table that shows all the data that are in mySQL table but it does like this:

When I open this frame, I see the last data that I added and when I click on Close button, at first the last data will be deleted from my table and then the frame will be closed and if I open the frame again, I see whole data which are in MySQL tabel and also I will see the last data for two times. Why?

I want to show my data from MySQL table in my GUI table. If I close my frame and then open that, I want to see all those data that I added before + the new data that I added it recently.

user class:

```
public class Manager {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    private static Connection conn = DBManager.getConnection();
    public static Admin admin;
    private static List<Birth> birthList;

    public static void addBirth(String name, String family, String fatherName, String mName, String dOfBirth, String pOfBirth) {
        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO birthtable(name,family,fatherName,motherName,dateOfBirth,placeOfBirth)" + "VALUES('" + name + "','" + family + "','" + fatherName + "','" + mName + "','" + dOfBirth + "','" + pOfBirth + "')");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public static boolean isAddBirth(String name, String family, String fatherName, String mName, String dOfBirth, String pOfBirth) {
        boolean bool = true;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        ResultSet rst = null;
        try {
            rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM birthtable");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            while (rst.next()) {
                if (rst.getString(2).equals(name) && rst.getString(3).equals(family) && rst.getString(4).equals(fatherName) && rst.getString(5).equals(mName) && rst.getString(6).equals(dOfBirth) && rst.getString(7).equals(pOfBirth)) {
                    bool = false;
                } else {
                    bool = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return bool;
    }

    public static void addToBirthListFromMySQL() throws SQLException {
        Birth list1 = null;
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM birthtable");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String s1 = rs.getString(2);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s1 = null;
            }
            String s2 = rs.getString(3);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s2 = null;
            }
            String s3 = rs.getString(4);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s3 = null;
            }
            String s4 = rs.getString(5);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s4 = null;
            }
            String s5 = rs.getString(6);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s5 = null;
            }
            String s6 = rs.getString(7);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s6 = null;
            }
            list1 = new Birth(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6);
            birthList = admin.getBirthList();
            if (birthList == null) {
                birthList = new ArrayList<Birth>();
            }
            birthList.add(list1);
        }
        admin.setBirthList(birthList);
    }
}
```

BirthList frame:

```
public class BirthList extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Admin admin;
    List<Birth> list;
    DefaultTableModel model;

    /** Creates new form BirthList */
    public BirthList(Admin admin) {
        initComponents();
        this.admin = admin;
        Manager.admin = admin;
        try {
            Manager.addToBirthListFromMySQL();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BirthList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        fillTable();
    }

    private void cancleBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        for(int i=0;i<jTable1.getRowCount();i++){

           model.removeRow(i);
           model.fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure?", "Message", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if(r==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            this.dispose();    // TODO add your handling code here:
    }      

    public void fillTable() {
        String[] columNames = {"name", "family", "father's name", "mother's name", "date of birth", "place of birth"};
        List<Birth> birth = admin.getBirthList();
        if (birth==null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Death list is empty! at first ,add a person.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            Object[][] data = new Object[birth.size()][columNames.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                Birth birth1 = birth.get(i);

                data[i][0] = birth1.getName();
                data[i][1] = birth1.getFamily();
                data[i][2] = birth1.getFatherName();
                data[i][3] = birth1.getMotherName();
                data[i][4] = birth1.getDateOfBirth();
                data[i][5] = birth1.getPlaceOfBirth();
            }
            model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columNames);
            jTable1.setModel(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function "isAddBirth" is kind of, how to say... Why not doing a real SQL request instead of numerous iteration with a result set ? At least add a break into your resultset when it's found ...

Comment: would you please show me an example?

Comment: You still haven't accepted the answers from yesterday and the day before and the day before..... Why should be continue to help someone who doesn't appreciate the time and effort we spend helping?

Comment: I will appreciate the time and effort,but really I have bad connection and I can just be in one page,if I close this page ,I can not open it easily,and I always use refreshing the page:((

Comment: You connection works good enough to ask a question so it works good enough to read the answers and accept an answer.

Comment: for asking a question I will open the other Firefox page and then I asked my question with difficulty and then I use refreshing page for that.

Comment: Johanna, it's amazing how little you understand the community here.  Frankly, I'm stunned that people continue to give you any help.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly said, I am going to sound harsh, but this is the truth. The posted code is *terrible*. I know this should have been a comment, but this isn't going to fit in a comment. I just wanted to highly recommend you to take the following steps:

1. Learn Java here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/
2. Learn SQL here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/
3. Learn JDBC here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/
4. Learn DAO here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html

From 1. you should learn under each how and when (*not*) to use `static`. From 2. you should under each learn how to execute specific queries with help of `WHERE` clause so that you don't need to haul the whole database contents into Java's memory and looping through it just only to check if something exist. From 3. you should learn under each how to acquire and close resources in a proper manner to avoid resource leaks and how to use `PreparedStatement` to save your code from SQL Injections. From 4. you should learn under each how to put the complete JDBC picture nicely together.

Hope this helps. Much good luck.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer 1,000 times, and 1,000 more times.

Answer (score 1):

For your isAddBirth request, it can be replaced by

```
SELECT * 
FROM birthtable
WHERE fatherName LIKE \"pFatherName\"
AND name LIKE \"pName\";
```

And so on for the other criteria, then in the result set you'll have no result, or only one (supposing you had in your table a way to not duplicate entries according to their name, family name date of birth ...)

Maybe it could be useful for you to name your  sql tables and sql rows name with Java variables, so in case of modifications there won't be coherence problems.

```
final String birthTable = "birthtable";
final String fatherName = "fatherName";
```

Then you can simply see if the result set has returned something or not and set up your return value according to this.